# Excel - Calculated Field COUNT function

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Why does the calculated field (Count(Age)) evaluate to 1 (For row Mark below) when it should evaluate to 3? I have been searching around the internet & people say that 'Calculated Fields always SUM 1st & then perform the calculation' so is this essentially:

Summing the 'Mark' ages & then counting that aggregated number?

Calculated field calculation is: `=COUNT(Age)`

[image]